How can I proxy to an upstream that only accepts HTTP 1.1 in Node.js?
I have a legacy Express app that uses http-proxy to proxy calls to an upstream application. I'm migrating both of these apps to Azure Container Apps which use Envoy under the hood when ingress is over HTTP. Envoy does not support HTTP 1.0 - notably it also seems to send transfer chunked encoding responses which cause the Express application to get a ECONNRESET signal when moderately large files are sent (>200kb) resulting in partial downloads.
How can I either a:) get Envoy to respond without transfer chunked encoding bearing in mind I don't have access to the configuration, or b:) how can I get Node to proxy requests properly using transfer chunked encoding?

I had a similar problem recently with ACA and http-proxy-middleware which uses http-proxy under the hood. I had the same symptom of partial responses with large JSON payloads anywhere above about 65 KB.
This is based on the an answer you got for your other post, where the Connection: Close header was causing problems because it was being forwarded and closing off rather than keep-aliving.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78660982/7503315
For http-proxy-middleware, this worked.
function onProxyRes(proxyRes, req, res) {
  proxyReq.setHeader('connection', '');
}

Looks like the same can be done for http-proxy.
proxy.on('proxyReq', function(proxyReq, req, res, options) {
  proxyReq.setHeader('connection', '');
});

Hope that works for you.
